# How to add Firebase auth onCreate listener in Admin Sdk

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I want to run a listener in Firebase Admin SDK that runs whenever a new account is created. It is possible to do this in cloud functions as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation. Can the same be done in Firebase Admin SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There is no `onCreate` listener in the Auth SDKs.

Since creating a user from the authentication SDK happens completely under control of your code, you're expect to handle any downstream actions in your own code once the user creation completes.

For example, in the documentation on [creating a user with the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) for Node.js, you can put any code that needs to run after the user has been created in the `then()` callback.

Comment: What I needed to do was that after a user creates a account on website, to run the user onCreate listener in admin sdk. I'll add a workaround and run a cloud functions which runs on user onCreate, adds a document to Firestore, and then there's a firestore listener in admin sdk. Would be great tho if the user onCreate listener is added to admin sdk just like the one in cloud functions